# 特定のファイル名を指定してサブディレクトリごとコピーしたい

Tags: windows, batch-file

バッチファイルでの動作を考えています。
カレントディレクトリ(target)からサブディレクトリの階層はバラバラですが「test.txt」を探して、目標のディレクトリ(dist)にディレクトリ階層を再現してコピーをしたいです。
すみません。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ROBOCOPY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx)でしょうか。

```
C:> dir /b
target
dist

C:> ROBOCOPY target dist test.txt /S
...
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。ROBOCOPYについて調べた上で回答の通り実行した結果、思った通りに動作しました。